# How to use std::map in three dimensional array for storing/retrieving key with specific value

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stdmap

Could you let us know how to use std:map as three dimension array? I wanted to access the individual elements as like mymap[i][j][k] to check if it exists and if it exists what value it contains and if it matches with my expected value. if it matches with my expected value then delete the entry (key,value) from map. This is how I created three dimensional array and iterator -

```
     std::map<int, map<int, map<int, unsigned long long int> > > MyMap;
     std::map<int, map<int, map<int, unsigned long long int> > >::iterator it;

    if (I==0 && j==4 && k==0) MyMap[i][j][k]= MemAddress.unlonglong(); //store a value to key 
    //Now I want to check if key exists where i=0,j=4,k=0 and if it is having "0x1234567" as expected value. If key value matches with my expected value then delete the key-value entry from MyMap and print whole table (MyMap) at the end.
```

Comment: I would suggest: make a `struct point { int a; int b; int c; };` and use `std::map<point, unsigned long long int>`.

Comment: Can you please provide snippet of the code?

Comment: @Krom or a `std:map<std::tuple<int,int,int>, unsigned long long int>`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. You could use a custom struct as a key like @Krom suggested, as follows:

```
struct Key { int a, b, c; };
(...)
std::map<Key, unsigned long long int> MyMap;
```

You can also use a tuple:

```
std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, unsigned long long int> MyMap;
```

Or use pairs inside pairs (I don't think you should do it this way because it isn't clean)

```
std::map<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>, unsigned long long int> MyMap;
```

Just using the struct is probably the cleanest option.
Using the struct, you could then access it this way (following your example code):

```
if (I==0 && j==4 && k==0) MyMap[{i, j, k}]= MemAddress.unlonglong();
```

To insert a new element you can also use:

```
MyMap.insert(std::make_pair<Key, unsigned long long int>({i, j, k}, MemAddress.unlonglong());
```

Comment: Thank you for inputs. I am getting following error when I tried to assign key a value (MyMap[{I, j, k}]) =MemAddress.unlonglong();) I am getting below error. it is not allowing me to use {} inside MyMap[]. error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token  , error: expected ‘]’ before ‘{’ token, error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token, error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token.

Comment: If I do like this -  Key key1{I,j,k};  MyMap[key1]=address.unlonglong;  it throws a warning. "warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x" is it ok?

Comment: To initialize structs with a initializer list you need to use c++11. So it just a matter of adding the "-std=c++0x" compiler flag